# How do i setup jQuery footables to show the toggle

Tags: jquery

As the question suggests i cannot seem to configure foo-tables, even in the most basic way - 3 columns, last column is the toggle which shows the detail row. My markup code is thus:

```js
$('.footable').footable({});
```

```css
.footable {
  font-size: 88%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table footable fw-labels" data-page-navigation=".pagination" data-page-size="6">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th data-toggle="true">Details</th>
      <th data-hide="all">Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr class="row-primary">
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-primary">"Primary"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-primary&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-info">
      <td><span class="label label-info">Info</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-info">"Info"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-info&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-success">
      <td><span class="label label-success">Success</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-success">"Success"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-success&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-warning">
      <td><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-warning">"Warning"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-warning&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-danger">
      <td><span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-danger">"Danger"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-danger&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-alert">
      <td><span class="label label-alert">Alert</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-alert">"Alert"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-alert&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-system">
      <td><span class="label label-system">System</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-system">"System"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-system&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-dark">
      <td><span class="label label-dark">Dark</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-dark">"Dark"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-dark&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-primary">
      <td><span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-primary">"Primary"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-primary&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-info">
      <td><span class="label label-info">Info</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-info">"Info"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-info&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-success">
      <td><span class="label label-success">Success</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-success">"Success"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-success&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-warning">
      <td><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-warning">"Warning"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-warning&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-danger">
      <td><span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
      </td>
      <td>This is a Footable expandable <b class="text-danger">"Danger"</b> row</td>
      <td>You can use this style by formatting the table row like this <code>&lt;tr class=&quot;row-danger&quot;&gt;</code>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="footer-menu">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <nav class="text-right">
          <ul class="pagination hide-if-no-paging"></ul>
        </nav>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I have an example template from which i got his code which works perfectly - but in the actual app im building the third row which should be hidden until toggled is un-rendered and shows as a third column. My setup is as follows:

- FooTable - Version : 2.0.3
- jQuery-1.11.1
- jQuery UI - v1.11.0 - 2014-06-26
- Chrome : Version 46.0.2490.80 m

Any pointers appreciated - thanks in advance.
**BTW i have the correct footables css file referenced in my app (not shown in code snippet above)**